# typescript number in c# float

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, entity-framework-6

I have `SomeActionMethod([FromBody]MyClassWithAFloatProperty input)`, `input` has a float property(in c#) and the corresponding typescript property is a `number`.

As soon as the request hits the server the entire object(`input`) is `null`.

What to do ?

Comment: Could you please share the request details what you send to the back end from `TypeScript`? Thank you!

Comment: And the code of `MyClassWithFloatProperty` could also help.

Comment: You should share your angular http part of your code.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `float` if you can help it  because JavaScript numbers are twice as wide

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a serialization issue. The input is not properly deserialized.

1. Make sure that you have no typos, and that the properties of your C# class match 1-1 with the JSON object you send to your backend
2. Make sure that the float you send has the same localization with the float expected. If the local of your frontend is different from your backend 1.2 from the frontend can't be deseriealized without some custom deserializer to 1,2
3. Make sure that there is no custom filter that messes up your input.
4. Check your event viewer for Application errors. Maybe this will let you know what's wrong.

Share some more code for us to help you.